# Why don't we use calloc() insted of malloc() while creating linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

When we create a Linked List in C. In that, we have to allocate memory **Dynamically**. So we can use `malloc()` and `calloc()`, but most of the time programmers use `malloc()` instead of `calloc()`. I don't understand why?

This is a node -

```C
struct node  
{  
    int data;  
    struct node *next;    
};
```

Now we are intinalizing the ptr -

```c
struct node *ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Now here we are using malloc() So why most of the programmers don't use calloc() instead of malloc(). What difference does it make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a more realistic scenario:

```
struct person {
    struct person *next;
    char *name;
    char *address;
    unsigned int numberOfGoats;
};

struct person * firstPerson = NULL;
struct person * lastPerson = NULL;

struct person * addPerson(char *name, char *address, int numberOfGoats) {
    struct person * p;

    p = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if(p != NULL) {

        // Initialize the data

        p->next = NULL;
        p->name = name;
        p->address = address;
        p->numberOfGoats= numberOfGoats;

        // Add the person to the linked list

        p->next = lastPerson;
        lastPerson = p;
        if(firstPerson == NULL) {
            firstPerson = p;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

For this example, you can see that `calloc()` may cost CPU time (filling the memory with zero) for no reason at all because every field in the structure is set to a useful value anyway.

If a small amount of the structure isn't set (e.g. `numberOfGoats` is left as zero), then it's still likely to be faster to set that field to zero instead of setting the whole thing to zero.

If a large amount of the structure isn't set, then `calloc()` can make sense.

If none of the structure is set, then you shouldn't have allocated memory for nothing.

In other words; for most scenarios, `calloc()` is worse (for performance).